# Calculating the distance between two points in python

Tags: graph

I am trying to get my code to calculate the distance between turning point locations on the two graphs I have plotted.

The code needs to compare the location of the first turning point on graph 1 to the location of the first turning point on graph 2. This step is then repeated on the remaining turning points.

The reason I am doing this is as I am trying to measure graph similarity after simplification. I will attach the code as well as the data files if anyone has anything to add.

Thanks.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "compute point distance), you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job. Calculates the distance between 2 points in the cartesian space
`np.sqrt(pow((pointA.x - pointB.x), 2) + pow(pointA.y - pointB.y, 2))`

Comment: Why mix numpy methods with builtin? They could both be `pow` calls or `**` operators, or numpy calls. I'd personally recommend builtins unless OP plans to vectorize it, since then it'd be more portable.

Comment: Not an expert in Python, I'm a javascript developer. It's up to him to follow the best practices.

Comment: Understandable, I've been in the exact opposite position before. I'll still leave my comment for future readers though.